# android asynctask illegalargumentexception

Tags: android, android-asynctask, xmlhttprequest, http-get, illegalstateexception

i have one asynctask class.i try to send http request.i also wrote another asynctask class,i sent some strings with http request(GET) and now i want to send json string.i deserialized json and i want to send my son.but i have illegalargumentexception
p.s i successfully deserialized and i can show my json in Log.but i have no idea what is a wrong in my async task class

```
public void SendFacebookIdToServer1(final String my_json) {
    class HttpGetAsyncTask2 extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        ProgressDialog pDialog;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());

            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
            pDialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_progressdialog);

        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            try {

                HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                SendUrl = SendUrl + my_json;
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(SendUrl.trim());

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                System.out.println("httpResponse");
                InputStream inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity()
                        .getContent();
                InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(
                        inputStream);
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
                        inputStreamReader);
                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

                String bufferedStrChunk = null;
                while ((bufferedStrChunk = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    stringBuilder.append(bufferedStrChunk);
                    System.out.println(SendUrl);
                }
                System.out.println("Returning value of doInBackground :"
                        + stringBuilder.toString());
                return stringBuilder.toString();

            } catch (ClientProtocolException cpe) {
                System.out
                        .println("Exception generates caz of httpResponse :"
                                + cpe);
                cpe.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException ioe) {
                System.out
                        .println("Second exception generates caz of httpResponse :"
                                + ioe);
                ioe.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            Log.e("result isssssssss", result);

            if (pDialog != null) {
                pDialog.dismiss();

                pDialog = null;
            }



        }
    }

    HttpGetAsyncTask2 httpGetAsyncTask2 = new HttpGetAsyncTask2();

    httpGetAsyncTask2.execute();
}
```

i called my function like this

```
SendFacebookIdToServer1(jsonDeserialize);
```

[image]

if anyone knows solution please help me
thanks

Comment: post the full stacktrace]

Comment: You haven't posted enough of your logcat and PLEASE don't post screenshots - edit your question and post logcat in a code block.

Comment: is `jsonDeserialize` a `String` or it's a `JSONObject` ?

Comment: jsonDeserialize is a string  @Mohammad Rahchamani

Comment: @chromelend why are you adding your json to your `SendUrl` ?

Comment: problem solved thanks everyone space was problem